# Why have we used double quotes in return i+"";

Tags: java

When I run the program after removing +"" from return statement of toString() a compile time error comes. No idea why.. Please tell why it is like that.

```
class Test
    {
        int i;
        Test(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return i;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return i+"";
        }
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            Test t1 = new Test(100);
            Test t2 = new Test(110);
            System.out.println(t1);
            System.out.println(t2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the function is returning string, You are returning it int if you remove +"".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toString` method's `return` type is a `String`, so you can't just

```
return i;
```

because you would be returning an `int`; it needs to be converted to a `String`, & that's exactly what

```
return i+"";
```

does. You can also use

```
return String.valueOf(i); // If you wanted something more "explicit"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` is of type `int`

`return` type of method `toString()` is `String`.

Needs to be convert to a `String`.

So concat it with `""`, result is string `i+""`.

Anything within `""` represents a string.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` returns a `String`. The variable `i` is an `int`. Type conversion doesn't work here, so you need to convert it to a `String` by concatenating it with `""`.